# virtumart in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I have made a site site in joomla & in this i use Virtuemart. 
In virtumart when user purchse the item then there is a thank page. In this thank page i want to add one module which contain text so that user can change it later. But i am not be able to show it on thanks page. I want to show this module in thanks page data means in between the data not at bottom of thanks page.means in between the lines of thanks page. how can i include my custom module in thanks page of virtuemart.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some programming for something like this... 
Check this out http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/renderModule

You can [install JUMI](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/1023), modify the *Thank You* article and add following php script to the article:

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'yourmodule', 'You Module Title' );
$attribs['style'] = 'xhtml'; // this is optional, if set template XHTML style will be used
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule( $module, $attribs );
```